# Can we edit and transfer files in FTE

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I have a question, When fte picks a file, convert the record delimiters into messages.  At the end of the message, can we add one EOF message?

Comment: Any reason why you want to send EOF message? Because FTE writes the file at the destination only after it receives complete file from source.

Answer (score 0):

FTE provides several call-out points at which you can perform almost any manipulation.  In this case, the post-transfer destination call can be used to append any data you wish to the end of the file prior to marking the transfer complete.

Please see [*Running programs before or after a transfer*](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/invoking.htm) in the Infocenter.